# Не отрабатывают хуки из папки custom_hooks для Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

В Gitlab Community создаю папку custom_hooks и создаю там pre-receive hook, но он не отрабатывает. Что нужно еще сделать, чтобы он вызывался?

Comment: добавить биты исполнимости? `chmod +x /путь/к/файлу`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, оказывается не хватало chmod +x /путь/к/файлу. Как же тяжело windows-пользователю в линукс =)